# Maintain persistent bandwidth on esp8266

Tags: arduino, esp8266

I'm working with esp8266 Arduino (via Adafruit Feather Huzzah) I'm trying to continuously write 3 characters to a TCP socket, but there's nothing continuous about it. It has a very regular pattern of high and low bandwidth. It writes at a very high rate for ~10 seconds, and then a very low rate for 4 seconds (see graph of received packets)

```
//...
void loop() {
  if (!client.connect(host, port)) {
    delay(10);
    return;
  }

  for (int i=0; i < 1024; i++){
    client.print(String(analogRead(A0)) + "\r\n");
    delay(1);
  }
}
```

Number of received messages (v2.2.0 and 2.3.0 firmware)

[image: Number of received messages]

Any ideas if it's the wifi driver, something in the chip or hardware timers that I can't get around... or maybe something else?

-- Update --

I have tested this with master, and it gets a different, but still bursty result. It appears that it now "catches up", instead of slowing down, but it's still on a ~10s / ~4s pattern. What could be causing this? What are the options for mitigation?

[image]

Comment: What version of the ESP8266 Arduino core are you using?

Comment: Can you pull the newest git? Shortly after that release a large rewrite was committed that fixed a lot of throughput issues with WiFiClient

Comment: Yes! Thanks. I will try that and report back. Thanks

Comment: I did. Thanks! Similar but less bad issue. See updated question.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is not a proper answer, but this may be due to the Nagle's algorithm the runs by default on espduino. Try turning it off using the `client.setNoDelay(false)` method. Also, if you post your code other people (like myself) can test it!!